# Titanium require('alloy/measurement') error

Tags: android, titanium, require, measurement

I Try require this

```
var measurement = require('alloy/measurement')
```

and open windows with this code

```
$.container.setBorderRadius((OS_ANDROID ? measurement.dpToPX($.container.width) : $.container.width) / 2);
```

and happen this error

```
[DEBUG] Module: Loading module: alloy/measurement -> Resources/alloy/measurement.js
[DEBUG] AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
[WARN]  dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a8bba8)
[ERROR] TiApplication: (main) [99,34734] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ws.xxx.zzz/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy; Titanium 3.2.2,2014/03/05 12:22,96e9a07
```

**My environment**

- Titanium SDK 3.2.2.GA
- Android 4.4.4 with Nexus 4
- Titanium Client 3.2.3 and Alloy 1.3.1
- OSX 10.9.4

Comment: Are you sure your measurement module is in the alloy folder? can you provide a bit more code?

Comment: Yes. Maybe this error is borderRadius dimensions... I will check again